# Finding the interval of convergence and the center of $\sum (3n)^n(x+5)^n$ and $\sum \frac{(x+4)^n}{(n+3)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I did:

$\lim \sqrt[n]{ (3n)^n|x+5|^n} = \lim (3n)|x+5| = \infty$

It diverges for all x ($I = \{\emptyset\}$) and the center is -5. How do I solve this limit when $x = -5$? Does it converge?

For the second one:

$\lim \sqrt[n]{\frac{(x+4)^n}{(n+3)^n}} = \lim \frac{|x+4|}{n+3} = 0$

Does this mean it converges for all x and $I = ]-\infty,\infty[$? What happens when x = -4?

Comment: What happens if you substitute $x=-5$ and $x=-4$ in the terms of the series?

Comment: @bjorn93 The first one diverges and the second one converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-c)^n$ always converge at $x=c$. If you plug in $x=c$, its term becomes $a_n(c-c)^n=0$ for $n\geq 1$, so the series is simply
$$a_0+a_1\cdot 0+a_2\cdot 0+\dots=a_0+0+0+\dots=a_0 $$
That is, the sum is equal to the $0$-th term (or to $0$ if there is no $0$-th term). Thus, we immediately know your series are convergent at $x=-5$ and $x=-4$, respectively. 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}3n|x+5|=\infty $$
is true when $|x+5|>0\Leftrightarrow x\ne -5$.  So the root test tells us the first series is divergent for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-5\}$. If $|x+5|=0$, then $3n|x+5|=0$ for all $n$, so you get a constantly $0$ sequence. Its limit is clearly $0$.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x+4|}{n+3}=0$$
is true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, including $|x+4|=0$ (in that case $|x+4|/(n+3)=0$ for all $n$). So the second series is convergent for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. But in general, it's a good idea to separate the cases $|x-c|=0$ and $|x-c|\ne 0$ because the $0$ might cause problems.